# Calculating gain or loss in a partition SQL

Tags: sql-server, min

With SQL partitions min and max values are easy to find, but how is Gain or Loss determined over a partition?

This brings in the time element to compare min and max. If max occurs later in time than min, that would be a "Gain".  If min occurs later, that would be a "Loss".

How might the GainorLoss column be calculated?

```
CREATE TABLE Weights (id int, date date, person varchar(40), Weight int);

INSERT INTO Weights VALUES (1, '2022-09-01', 'Alice', 100); 
INSERT INTO Weights VALUES (2, '2022-10-01', 'Alice', 105); 
INSERT INTO Weights VALUES (3, '2022-11-01', 'Alice', 110); 
INSERT INTO Weights VALUES (4, '2022-12-01', 'Alice', 115); 
INSERT INTO Weights VALUES (5, '2022-09-01', 'Peter', 150); 
INSERT INTO Weights VALUES (6, '2022-10-01', 'Peter', 145); 
INSERT INTO Weights VALUES (7, '2022-11-01', 'Peter', 140); 
INSERT INTO Weights VALUES (8, '2022-12-01', 'Peter', 135);

select  
 person
 , date
 , weight
 , min(Weight) OVER (PARTITION BY person) as minWeight
 , max(Weight) OVER (PARTITION BY person) as maxWeight 
 --if max weight occurs after min weight, then "Gain" ELSE "Loss" AS GainorLoss
 from weights
```

Desired output:

| person | date | weight | minWeight | maxWeight | GainorLoss |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | 2022-09-01 | 100 | 100 | 120 | Gain |
| Alice | 2022-10-01 | 105 | 100 | 120 | Gain |
| Alice | 2022-11-01 | 110 | 100 | 120 | Gain |
| Alice | 2022-12-01 | 120 | 100 | 120 | Gain |
| Peter | 2022-09-01 | 150 | 135 | 150 | Loss |
| Peter | 2022-10-01 | 145 | 135 | 150 | Loss |
| Peter | 2022-11-01 | 140 | 135 | 150 | Loss |
| Peter | 2022-12-01 | 135 | 135 | 150 | Loss |

Comment: The desired results and sample data are different...?

Comment: I suspect your sample/expected results aren't really telling the full story here. Alice always gains weight, while Peter always loses. Someone that fluctuates would be a good example, who can have both gain and loss values.

Comment: Fixed the result set

Answer (score 0):

I think the result would be more accurate if you measure the original weight with the current weight.
Or you can measure the status from the prior weight and the current weight.
It's up to you to choose, or you could just use both methods, they can be combined off course.
And I also added a resulttype for when the weight did not changed, when there is no gain and no loss

**This method uses the original weight and the current weight to determine the gain-or-loss status**

```
declare @Weights TABLE (id int, [date] date, person varchar(40), Weight int)

INSERT INTO @Weights values 
(1, '2022-09-01', 'Alice', 100), (2, '2022-10-01', 'Alice', 105), 
(3, '2022-11-01', 'Alice', 110), (4, '2022-12-01', 'Alice', 115), 
(5, '2022-09-01', 'Peter', 150), (6, '2022-10-01', 'Peter', 145), 
(7, '2022-11-01', 'Peter', 140), (8, '2022-12-01', 'Peter', 135)


select t.person,
       t.[date],
       t.weight,
       t.minWeight,
       t.maxWeight,
       t.Original,
       case when t.Original > t.weight then 'Loss'
            when t.Original < t.weight then 'Gain'
            else 'Unchanged'
       end as GainOrLoss
from   ( select  w.person,
                 w.[date],
                 w.weight,
                 min(w.Weight) OVER (PARTITION BY w.person) as minWeight,
                 max(w.Weight) OVER (PARTITION BY w.person) as maxWeight,
                 FIRST_VALUE(w.Weight) OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY [date], id) as Original
         from    @weights w
       ) t
```

with this result

```
-------|----------|--------|-----------|-----------|--------|---------
person |date      |weight  |minWeight  |maxWeight  |Original GainOrLoss
-------|----------|--------|-----------|-----------|--------|---------
Alice  |2022-09-01| 100    |100        |115        |100     |Unchanged
Alice  |2022-10-01| 105    |100        |115        |100     |Gain
Alice  |2022-11-01| 110    |100        |115        |100     |Gain
Alice  |2022-12-01| 115    |100        |115        |100     |Gain
Peter  |2022-09-01| 150    |135        |150        |150     |Unchanged
Peter  |2022-10-01| 145    |135        |150        |150     |Loss
Peter  |2022-11-01| 140    |135        |150        |150     |Loss
Peter  |2022-12-01| 135    |135        |150        |150     |Loss
```

You can test and change is in this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4f6e26eb692d90dad2fb5cb9a0bc5b06)

---

**EDIT**

If you want to see the weight changes with regards to the prior weight, you can use the [LAG funtion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).
In my option this would be the best method to follow up someone's weight change.

**This method uses the prior weight and the current weight to determine the gain-or-loss status**

```
select t.person,
       t.[date],
       t.priorWeight,
       t.weight,
       case when t.priorWeight > t.weight then 'Loss'
            when t.priorWeight < t.weight then 'Gain'
            else 'nochange'
       end as GainOrLoss,
       t.minWeight,
       t.maxWeight
from   ( select  w.person,
                 w.[date],
                 w.weight,
                 min(w.Weight) OVER (PARTITION BY w.person) as minWeight,
                 max(w.Weight) OVER (PARTITION BY w.person) as maxWeight,
                 lag(w.Weight) over (partition by person order by [date]) as priorWeight
         from    @weights w
       ) t
```

```
-------|----------|------------|-------|----------|---------|---------
person |date      |priorWeight |weight |GainOrLoss|minWeight|maxWeight
-------|----------|------------|-------|----------|---------|---------
Alice  |2022-09-01|            |100    |nochange  |100      |115
Alice  |2022-10-01|100         |105    |Gain      |100      |115
Alice  |2022-11-01|105         |110    |Gain      |100      |115
Alice  |2022-12-01|110         |115    |Gain      |100      |115
Peter  |2022-09-01|            |150    |nochange  |135      |150
Peter  |2022-10-01|150         |145    |Loss      |135      |150
Peter  |2022-11-01|145         |140    |Loss      |135      |150
Peter  |2022-12-01|140         |135    |Loss      |135      |150
```

And again a [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fbfa89abb9902b6260ac3e5a06e8eb7d) you can use to play with this query

You can combine the 2 methods offcourse

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FIRST_VALUE` to get the first or the last value based on an order.

The example below calculates 2 GainOrLess results.
The 2nd is what you described. The 1st is what I think you want.
But with the current sample data they give same result.

> ```
> select *
> , CASE 
>   WHEN LastWeight > FirstWeight THEN 'Gain' 
>   WHEN LastWeight < FirstWeight THEN 'Loss' 
>   ELSE 'Same' 
>   END AS [GainOrLoss1]
> , CASE 
>   WHEN MaxWeightDate > MinWeightDate THEN 'Gain' 
>   WHEN MaxWeightDate < MinWeightDate THEN 'Loss' 
>   ELSE 'Same' 
>   END AS [GainOrLoss2]
> from 
> (
> select  
>  person
>  , [date] 
>  , weight
>  , FIRST_VALUE(Weight) OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY [date], id) as FirstWeight
>  , FIRST_VALUE(Weight) OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY [date] DESC, id DESC) as LastWeight 
>  , FIRST_VALUE([date]) OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY Weight, id) as MinWeightDate
>  , FIRST_VALUE([date]) OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY Weight DESC, id DESC) as MaxWeightDate
>  from weights
> ) q
> ORDER BY person, [date]
> ```

> ```
> person | date       | weight | FirstWeight | LastWeight | MinWeightDate | MaxWeightDate | GainOrLoss1 | GainOrLoss2
> :----- | :--------- | -----: | ----------: | ---------: | :------------ | :------------ | :---------- | :----------
> Alice  | 2022-09-01 |    100 |         100 |        115 | 2022-09-01    | 2022-12-01    | Gain        | Gain       
> Alice  | 2022-10-01 |    105 |         100 |        115 | 2022-09-01    | 2022-12-01    | Gain        | Gain       
> Alice  | 2022-11-01 |    110 |         100 |        115 | 2022-09-01    | 2022-12-01    | Gain        | Gain       
> Alice  | 2022-12-01 |    115 |         100 |        115 | 2022-09-01    | 2022-12-01    | Gain        | Gain       
> Peter  | 2022-09-01 |    150 |         150 |        135 | 2022-12-01    | 2022-09-01    | Loss        | Loss       
> Peter  | 2022-10-01 |    145 |         150 |        135 | 2022-12-01    | 2022-09-01    | Loss        | Loss       
> Peter  | 2022-11-01 |    140 |         150 |        135 | 2022-12-01    | 2022-09-01    | Loss        | Loss       
> Peter  | 2022-12-01 |    135 |         150 |        135 | 2022-12-01    | 2022-09-01    | Loss        | Loss
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=80403d2fdaa4a96d11901bf070a0ab28)*

Comment: So OK to use alternative partitions in the select statement.  That's helpful.

Comment: I can idetify the records with the Min and Max values with this: